# Visual Studio ASP development - changing database connection in apre-existing project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm brand new to developing websites with visual studio and ASP.net. I have 2 questions which I would be very appreciative if you could help me with.

My main question is. I've inherited a visual studio project that i need to expand upon. I've gotten it running on localhost but it is still connected to the old database. I've made a copy of that database and would like to connect to it while I'm testing things out rather then use the live database. Could anyone explain how I change database connections.

Secondly, I have experience of writing PHP shich is basically scripting HTML but this seems very different. Could anyone point me to a relevant tutorial which will let me know how I am supposed to develop websites on this platform. I've been exploring the project files and comparing it to the html source and can't really make connections so a visual studio + asp tutorial which is of good quality would be very helpful to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the database connnetion change this in the web.config file in a section called connectionstrings. For example:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="test.DbConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="server=local;database=mydatabase;Integrated Security=FALSE;user=sa;pwd=1234;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for HTML tutorials.  I learned a LONG time ago off of http://www.htmlgoodies.com.  That's only going to get you so far.  Practice and http://www.asp.net is a great site to learn.

You should look at converting the WebSite Project [WSP] to a Web Application Project [WAP] (Google it) and take full advantage of the file transformation it offers.  That way you only muck around in the web.config file once.  Even for experienced developers, it is tedious to modify the web.config file for a deployment into 'DEV', 'TEST', and then 'PROD'.  I'd rather press the 'publish' button and it do the work for me.